# C# Convert Excel .xlsx columns to JSON using oledb, is this still the best way to proceed?

Tags: c#, json, excel, oledb

I have 2 populated columns in Excel Latitude and Longitude. I would like to combine these columns for each row and convert to JSON looking something like this example `"{\"Locations\" : [[50.452603, 30.522025],[30.621929, 31.012975]]}";` I've read a good way to start is to use oledb data adapter to fill a datatable. But the examples normally refer to .xls files, where as I am using the newer .xlsx. Is this still the best way of proceeding?

I have tried the below but am getting an error System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Cannot update.  Database or object is read-only.' It also doesnt like the dataGridView1.DataBind(), saying there is not a definition for DataBind.

```
String sConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
"Data Source=" + "A:\\Home\\Test.xlsx;" +
"Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";

OleDbConnection objConn = new OleDbConnection(sConnectionString);

objConn.Open();

OleDbCommand objCmdSelect = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM MyRange1", objConn);

OleDbDataAdapter objAdapter1 = new OleDbDataAdapter();

objAdapter1.SelectCommand = objCmdSelect;

DataSet objDataset1 = new DataSet();

objAdapter1.Fill(objDataset1, "XLData");

dataGridView1.DataSource = objDataset1.Tables[0].DefaultView;
dataGridView1.DataBind();

objConn.Close();
```

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Sorry yes I have and I am getting errors. Such as the file is read only. Error: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Cannot update.  Database or object is read-only.'

Comment: No, using OLEDB isn't a good way to proceed, because it only works on Windows and requires installing the Access drivers. `xlsx` files are ZIP files containing XML files so they *don't* need OLEDB at all. You can read the XML files directly or even better, use a library like ExcelDataReader or EPPlus to read the data

Comment: Thank you, that's interesting. And from there its quite easy to convert to JSON? I'm quite new to C#.

Comment: Using what format? There are several ways you can represent data. What you posted shows what looks like one attribute per sheet or table, containing an array of row data. It's up to the client to guess what the row values are though.  A *more* popular option used in data science is to represent data as *columns (actually Series) of values. *Another* option is to export an array of objects. Each object is one row, with one attribute per cell. That's easy to read but uses more space. If you search for `DataTable to JSON` you'll find several snippets that produce different formats.

Comment: EPPlus has [a JSON export feature](https://github.com/EPPlusSoftware/EPPlus/wiki/JSON-Export) that exports both the value and text of a cell.

Comment: Ok thank you very much for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, using OLEDB isn't a good way to proceed, because it only works on Windows and requires installing the Access drivers. `xlsx` files are ZIP files containing XML files so they don't need OLEDB at all. You can read the XML files directly or even better, use a library like [ExcelDataReader](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader) or [EPPlus](https://www.epplussoftware.com/), or [ClosedXML](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML) to read the data. Those are just the 3 I remember right now.

With ExcelDataReader you can read Excel data with a DbDataReader and even load the data into a DataSet directly, with a single call to `AsDataset()`

```
using (var stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream));
do
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        // reader.GetDouble(0);
    }
} while (reader.NextResult()); //Move to the next sheet
```

or

```
using (var stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream));
var result = reader.AsDataSet();
```